# Inputting string read from a .txt file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I am making a flashcard like app for my high school software project. I am able to store words and their respective translation by writing them to a file, but I was wondering if there was a possible way to read them into a 2d array.

Could I separate them with commas, or some other character?

Additionally would there be a way to link the words and their respective translations. For example if I called word 'x', is there a function to call word 'translated x' if it is in an array?

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down the problem a bit.

- read the file
- parse each line in the file to determine a `word` and a `translation`
- store the `word` and the `translation` in a data structure (@Glen Pierce's suggestion about using a map is a good one)

Let's say our file looks like this, we use a comma to delimit the word and the translation (this is also the extent of my Spanish vocabulary):

```
hello,hola
good,bueno
```

Now some code, let's read the file into a map.

```
// a map of word to translation
Map<String, String> wordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// a class that can read a file (we wrap the file reader in a buffered reader because it's more efficient to read a file in chunks larger than a single character)
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my-file.txt"));

// a line from the file
String line;

// read lines until we read a line that is null (i.e. no more lines)
while((line = fileReader.getLine()) != null) {
    // split the line, returns an array of parts
    String[] parts = line.split(",");

    // store the parts in meaningful variables
    String word = parts[0];
    String translation = parts[1];

    // now, store the word and the translation in the word map
    wordMap.put(word, translation);
}

// close the reader (note: you should do this with a try/finally block so that if you throw an exception, you still close the reader)
fileReader.close();
```

So now we have a map that has all the words and translations in the file. Given a word, you can retrieve the translation like this:

```
String word = "hello";
String translation = wordMap.get(word);
System.out.println(word + " translates to " + translation);
```

Output:

```
hello translates to hola
```

I guess the next step is to have the user give you a word and for you to return the correct translation. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank-you so much for the answer, this is really helpful. Just a quick follow up question. The way you have structured the reading section, can it only store one pair of words at a time, or all of them? This doesn't really have any application to my project, but I am just interested to know. Thanks again!! :D

Comment: Sure, no problem. The reading section will read the whole file one line at a time, from each line it will extract the `word,translation` pair, and store that pair in the `wordMap`. So it only stores one pair per iteration of the loop, but it loops over every line in the file. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So it stores one pair at a time, and at the end of the while loop, it would be storing all the pairs at the same time? Thank-you for your patience. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: There's nothing simultaneous going on. It's just a step by step procedure. The loop says "I will read one line each time until I finish". If you have 10 lines in your file, then loop will execute 10 times, each time it will read a single line and put it into the map. After 10 lines have been read, the loop will finish and the map will contain 10 words, along with their matching translations.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it a bit more!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Maps. That way you could look up each word by the word itself rather than iterating through an Array. Maps use Key Value pairs. Unfortunately, they are unidirctional (you can't look up a key by it's value).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I had a look at maps, but couldn't find a way to allow the users to input their own words. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of programming!  It's not the Map's job to ask your user for input.  A Map is just a tool for the rest of your program to use to stash stuff and look it up again.  If you want your user to be able to add words, you've got to write code that asks the user to enter a word, asks the user to enter the translation, accepts those answers, and stores the words in your map.  Then you need to provide the user a means of specifying that he'd like to start entering words, start taking a quiz, and whatever else... Don't worry, it'll be fun!

Comment: I understand that, but I don't get how to link the users inputted words with the map, and how to create new maps when the user inputs more words...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the words in a text file (i.e., do they need to persist), or can you store them in memory?
If they need to be written to a text file, try this:

```
    // Create a file
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    // Initialize a print writer to print to the file
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Populate
    boolean stop = false;
    do {
        String word;
        String translation;
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine().trim() + " ";
        if (!word.equals("quit ")) {
            pw.print(word);
            System.out.print("Enter its translation: ");
            translation = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
            pw.println(translation);
        } else {
            stop = true;
        }
    } while (!stop);

    // Close the print writer and write to the file
    pw.close();

    // Initialize a scanner to read the file
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

    // Initialize a hash table to store the values from the file
    Hashtable<String, String> words = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    // Add the information from the file to the hash table
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileReader.nextLine();
        String[] array = line.split(" ");
        words.put(array[0], array[1]);
    }

    // Print the results
    System.out.println("Results: ");
    words.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));

    fileReader.close();
    keyboard.close();
```

Note that I am using a space to separate the word from its translation.  You can just as easily use a comma or a semicolon or what have you.  Just replace `line.split(" ")` with `line.split(< your separating character here>)` and concatenate it to the end of `word = keyboard.nextLine().trim()`.

If you don't need to save the information and just need to collect the user's input, it's even simpler:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Initialize a hash table to store the values from the user
    Hashtable<String, String> words = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    // Get the input from the user
    boolean stop = false;
    do {
        String word;
        String translation;
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
        if (!word.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.print("Enter its translation: ");
            translation = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
            words.put(word, translation);
        } else {
            stop = true;
        }
    } while (!stop);

    // Print the results
    System.out.println("Results: ");
    words.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));

    keyboard.close();
```